# Can I get a list of rows with varchar values that aren't castable to datetime?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2000, casting, varchar

I have a legacy SQL Server 2000 database that has one column that has a date that is stored as a varchar instead of a datetime for whatever reason.  I want to make a view against this data and use a datetime field instead of a varchar to make making a report against the field easier.  The good news is that *most* of the values look like they should be able to be cast directly into a datetime.

Of course, there apparently are some fields that were entered in such a way that they aren't castable to datetime.  Just for clarity's sake, here's how the table could look:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.user
(
    ...
    birthdate varchar(10)
    ...
)
```

And the view could look something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.UserView
AS
SELECT ...
       CAST(u.birthdate AS datetime) AS birthdate
       ...
FROM user u
WHERE ...
```

Is there any way I can:

1. Get a list of all the rows where birthdate cannot be cast into a datetime in case I can repair it?
2. In instances where I can't repair the value, make the value show up as NULL or maybe even something that is obviously *not* the user's real birthdate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [IsDate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx)

```
SELECT birthdate, ' ' _, *
FROM user u
WHERE IsDate(u.bithdate) != 1
```

and

```
SELECT ...
   CAST(CASE WHEN IsDate(u.birthdate) = 1 THEN u.birthdate ELSE NULL END AS datetime) AS birthdate
   ...
FROM user u
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the [T-SQL ISDATE() Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

show bad rows:

```
select * from dbo.user where isdate(birthdate)!=1
```

your view:

```
SELECT ...
    CASE
        WHEN isdate(birthdate)=1 THEN CAST(u.birthdate AS datetime)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Birthday
       ...
FROM user u
WHERE ...
```

Comment: It's a small thing, but good point on !=1 rather than =0.  While the this particular function always returns 1 or 0, many functions will return NULL for NULL inputs, and it's a good habit to be in to specifically test on the success result.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: NULL=0 is not true too, so it doesn't matter

Comment: @wqw - it would matter for the first sample. If he wrote =0 rather than != 1 and this were a NULL becomes NULL function, NULL records wouldn't be returned.

Comment: Both "null!=1" and "null=0" are false. Any comparison to null evaluates to false.

Comment: FYI, isdate() does not ever return NULL